# App has stopped working AFTER PASSING A VARIABLE between Activities

Tags: android

This is the error after i tried to pass a variable between two activities

example:

Main Activity

```
Intent KMH = new Intent(Options.this,VolumeControlMAIN.class);
Bundle DistanceValue = new Bundle();
DistanceValue.putBoolean("distance", DistanceTX);
KMH.putExtras(DistanceValue);
startActivity(KMH);
```

Second Activity

```
Bundle distanceK = getIntent().getExtras();
value = distanceK.getBoolean("distance");
```

Here is my log cat.

```
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audiovolumecontrol/com.example.audiovolumecontrol.VolumeControlMAIN}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.example.audiovolumecontrol.VolumeControlMAIN.onCreate(VolumeControlMAIN.java:144)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-28 11:36:18.923: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  ... 11 more
```

Do i have to create an intent for every variable i want to parse or can i use a global intent and would pass all at once?

Can anyone identify what my log cat is asking me to do?

Comment: paste only relevant parts of the stack trace not the entire log and also format the same

Comment: what is `VolumeControlMAIN.java` line 144?

Comment: that is my main class

Comment: How do i know which parts are relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NameOfActivity.class);
i.putExtra("my_boolean_key", myBooleanVariable);
startActivity(i)
```

Retrieve in Second Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean myBooleanVariable = bundle.getBoolean("my_boolean_key");
```

use above code for the same.

Comment: I have done that already i just ran out of characters to specify that

Comment: The intent i code in my main activity and the bundle code in my second activity(the one i am parsing variables to?) yo specify a bundle in the second activity and not the main is this correct

Comment: do i have to make a intent for all my variables i want to parse such as boolean or int or can i utilise the same one to parse all my variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your first activity:

Intent KMH = new Intent(Options.this,VolumeControlMAIN.class);

KMH.putExtras("distance", DistanceTX);

KMH.putExtras("anotherValueKey","another Value");

startActivity(KMH);

And Use this code in your Second Activity

```
 Intent in=getIntent();

 boolean value = in.getBoolean("distance");
```

Comment: I dont understand are you saying replace my current code with the way you specified